# MYSQL query error

Tags: mysql

Is there something wrong with this code? I'm running MYSQL 5 I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc BLOB, review BLOB, url BLOB )'

Here's my query:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE videos(
                id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                title VARCHAR(50),
                desc BLOB,
                review BLOB,
                url BLOB
            )
") or die(mysql_error());
```

It looks alright to me. At first I thought it was the "BLOB" datatype but then I tried "TEXT" and it still messed up so I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`desc` is a **reserved keyword**, you need to escape it:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE videos(
                id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                title VARCHAR(50),
                `desc` BLOB,
                review BLOB,
                url BLOB
            )
")or die(mysql_error());
```

For the full list of reserved keywords, see [8.3. Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: :S wow good catch. I would have never guessed. If I query 'desc' will I have to escape it again?

Comment: @howdy-mcgee Yes, you will. You should name the column something else.

Answer (score 1):

`desc` ise reserved keyword for MySQL, you should cover it with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE videos (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`title` VARCHAR(50),
`desc` BLOB,
`review` BLOB,
`url` BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE videos(
                `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                `title` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                `desc` BLOB NULL,
                `review` BLOB NULL,
                `url` BLOB NULL
            )
")or die(mysql_error());
```